# Jquery: unable to show load the respective pages while checking or unchecking the checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a check box. I want to call two different php pages based on the checkbox `checked` and `uncheck` status.

But the below code is only calling the checked php pages.
What could be the reason?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function()
     {
     $('input[id^="test"]').on('click',function()
       {
         if ($('input[id^="test"]').checked)//when users click to on checkbox to check
         {

           $.ajax({
               url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=1",
               success: function(data){ 
                alert('Successfully updated...');
               }
             });
     } 
     else//when users uncheck the checkbox
       {    $.ajax({
               url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=2",
               success: function(data){
                 alert("uncheckde...");
               }
             });
        } 
        });
    });
         </script>
```

And in page

```
<?php //checkbox in a while loop

            echo " <input type='checkbox' id='test' value='".$row['id']."'/> ";
         ?>
```

Comment: use change event instead of click

Comment: Also, try using `$('input[id^="test"]').is(':checked')` as the conditional.

Comment: @karaxuna I chnaged, but still problem. It is calling only the second ajax function. if i checked or unchecked my checkboxes

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes solved.. `$('input[id^="test"]').is(':checked')` and changing `click` to `change`

Comment: @TiesonT.  Answer my question as you said in comment. I need to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

Try using `$('input[id^="test"]').is(':checked')` as the conditional. You can also use `$(this)` to reference the specific checkbox that triggered the event. So, here's your code cleaned up a bit:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[id^="test"]').on('click',function(e) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=1",
                    success: function(data){ 
                        alert('Successfully updated...');
                    }
                });
            } 
            else {    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=2",
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("uncheckde...");
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

One other change I would make would be to assign a class to your checkboxes, and target that instead of using the "starts with" selector (since not every browser supports it).

Answer (score 1):

It's your check for checked or not that isn't working. Use the `.is(':checked')` method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=cbx]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Checked');
        } else {
            alert('Not Checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(function()
     {
     $('input[id^="test"]').on('click',function()
       {
         if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")//when users click to on checkbox to check
         {

           $.ajax({
               url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=1",
               success: function(data){ 
                alert('Successfully updated...');
               }
             });
     } 
     else//when users uncheck the checkbox
       {    $.ajax({
               url: "updatestatus.php?id="+$(this).val()+"&status=2",
               success: function(data){
                 alert("uncheckde...");
               }
             });
        } 
        });
    });
```

Comment: better consider Tieson's note